# Can I install linux split among a main drive and a secondary usb-attached one?

Tags: linux, system-installation

I have an old thin client, that has 512MB of RAM and a 4GB flash disk-on-module drive.

I'm investigating if I can upgrade them - actually the chipset should support at least 1GB of RAM and I've read posts around the net of people who replaced the flash disk with a compact flash + adapter, but this is out of scope.

What I'd like to ask is: several linux distro come with a livecd or similar, that boots from a USB stick to be installed on disk and require several GB of disk space.

Is there a distro that can install a minimal OS portion on a drive (I'm thinking about the above mentioned 4GB flash disk) that's needed to boot and then install everything else on a usb-attached disk?

Comment: 512MB would be OK-ish for a text only linux system, but not enough to run X and a modern desktop environment or apps.  With that amount of RAM, I'd guess it's late 90s or early 2000s hardware - have you considered looking for a relatively recent (i.e. <10 year old or so) "one liter PC"? You can easily find various brands (HP, Dell, Lenovo, etc) on ebay for $30 to $50 USD or so, with 4GB or more RAM and a SATA drive (or at least an empty SATA port allowing you to add a cheap HDD or SSD).   4GB is enough for light graphical desktop usage.  They're pretty popular with people build "home labs".

Comment: Never heard about "one liter PC"'s, will look into those, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Any distribution can do this. Just set up your disks accordingly and, in the partitioning step of the installation process, make sure that you have `/usr` and `/var` mounted on your external disk. The details will depend on the distribution you choose, but they should all have a partitioning step that allows you to partition the drive, so make at least three partitions, and make them be mounted at:

- `/usr`
- `/var`
- `/home`

The `/home` partition will have all of your personal stuff so you usually want that to be as large as you can make it.

Alternatively, you can just install everything directly to the USB drive, and keep only `/boot` on your local drive. To do that, in the partitioning step, set `/boot` as the mountpoint of your internal drive, and then use the external drive as `/`.

Finally, you might simply want to try one of the many minimal Linux distributions out there such as [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) or [Puppy Linux](https://puppylinux-woof-ce.github.io/) (there are many more, just search for "minimal linux" or "tiny linux" or similar search terms).